# Firestore in Cloud Functions - Create a missing index through an error message

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

When using Firestore in Cloud Functions, how to use the [Create a missing index through an error message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing?authuser=0#create_a_missing_index_through_an_error_message) feature?

Basically, after I use a new Firestore query in my Cloud Function, where should I expect to find the ["error message [that] includes a direct link to create the missing index"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing?authuser=0#create_a_missing_index_through_an_error_message)?

**Update: add sample code based on a comment suggestion**

Assume the query below wasn't used before. After I deploy the function to Cloud Functions and use it, where can I find the automatically-created link for creating the missing index?

```js
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const db = admin.firestore();

export const posts = functions.https.onCall(async (
    data: { uid: string },
    context
  ) => {
  // ...

  const querySnapshot = await postsRef
    .where('uid', '==', data.uid)
    .orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
    .get();

  // ...
});
```

Comment: Could you post some code so that we can help you

Comment: @DarrowHartman I'm not sure if sample code is relevant here but added it. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you perform the query, the resulting promise will become rejected. Your code will need to catch that error from the rejected promise, then log the error object.  The url will be in the log message. (I'm assuming you're using node here, but the same error handling will apply to any language using its conventions for capturing and logging errors.)

Comment: (1) Note: I'm using Cloud Functions, but yeah, principle should be the same. (2) In my case, no such error happened, the query ran successfully. Perhaps my query already has an index? ... Don't think so, but will re-check, try with another query, and get back to you hopefully.

Comment: Update: yes, you're right. Indeed an error was logged. For future readers: you can find these logs in Firebase Console => Hosting => "Logs" tab.